# How to transform a matrix to upper-triangular with operation- tag elegantly?

Tags: programming, matrix

#### Description:

Recently, I have a thought that writing a function to show the `transformation process` when a matrix is transformed to upper-triangular.

#### My trail

Formatting the result(with the help of *Mr.Wizard* and *Öskå*)

```
augmentedMatrixForm[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
 TraditionalForm@
  MatrixForm@List@
   Grid[
    mat, Dividers -> {Length[mat] + 1 -> {Red, Dashed}, False}, Alignment -> Center]
```

Function `LadderMatrixSteps`

```
LadderMatrixSteps[mat_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@mat && Det@mat != 0 :=
 Block[{augmentedMat, finalLadder, row, ladderStep, ladderTransform},
   row = Length@mat;
   augmentedMat = Join[mat, IdentityMatrix@Length@mat, 2];
   ladderStep[0] = augmentedMat;
 (*=========================================*)
   ladderTransform[i_] :=
    {ladderStep[i] =
      MapAt[
       #/ladderStep[i - 1][[(i + 1)/2, (i + 1)/2]] &, ladderStep[i - 1], (i + 1)/2],
     ladderStep[i + 1] =
      MapAt[
       # - ladderStep[i][[(i + 1)/2]] #[[(i + 1)/2]] &,ladderStep[i], 
       List /@ Range[(i + 3)/2, row]]};
  (*==============Construct Results=================*)
   ladderTransform /@ Range[1, 2 row - 3, 2];
   ladderStep[2 row - 1] =
   MapAt[
    #/ladderStep[2 row - 2][[row, row]] &, ladderStep[2 row -2], row];
   (*============Show Results=================*)
  Row[
   augmentedMatrixForm /@
   Table[ladderStep[i], {i, 0, 2 row - 1}], Style["-\[Rule]", 20, Red]]
   // TraditionalForm
]
```

Test process

```
testMat= RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}];
LadderMatrixSteps[testMat]
```

> [image]

However, in my function `LadderMatrixSteps`, I use the construct `ladderStep[i]` to store the intermidiate results(like array in C). Although it works good, I think it is `not  suitable` in *Mathematica* .

#### Question

1. Is there other elegant method to relize my function `LadderMatrixSteps`(for example `Rule-Based`)?
2. Is it possible to add `tags` between two steps (I just add a decollator `"-\[Rule]"` in `Row`)? Namely, shown as below:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Another try

```
arrow = Graphics[{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}}]}, ImageSize -> {50,10}];

product[m_, n_] := Module[{s, t},
  {{Subscript[r, n]/m[[n, n]]}, t = MapAt[#/m[[n, n]] &, m, n],
   Table[
    s = Subscript[r, i] - t[[i, n]] Subscript[r, n];
    t = MapAt[# - t[[i, n]] t[[n]] &, t, i]; s,
    {i, n + 1, Length[m]}], t}
  ]

rowReduce[m_] := Module[{n = Length[m], mat, prt, rst},
  mat = {{}, Join[m, IdentityMatrix@n, 2]};
  rst = Flatten[FoldList[product[#1[[-1]], #2] &, mat, Range[n]], 1];
  prt = Partition[Drop[Rest@rst, -3], 2];
  Transpose[{
      augmentedMatrixForm /@ Transpose[prt][[1]],
      Overscript[arrow, Grid@Map[List, #]] & /@ Transpose[prt][[2]]
      }] // Grid // Print;
  rst[[-3]] // augmentedMatrixForm
  ]
```

The result is same with original code.

```
rowReduce[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 3}]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> [image: Blockquote]

**Origin**

This is my try.

```
divMat[m_, n_, a_] := MapAt[#/a &, m, n]
redMat[m_, n_] := Join[m[[1 ;; n]],
  Table[m[[i]] - m[[i, n]] m[[n]], {i, n + 1, Length[m]}]]
makeDivTag[n_, a_] := 
 Overscript["--->", Grid[{{"\[Times]", Subscript[r, n]/a}}]]
makeRedTag[m_, n_] := Overscript["--->",
  Grid[Table[{Subscript[r, i] - m[[i, n]] Subscript[r, n]}, {i, n + 1,
      Length[m]}]]]

rowReduce[mat_] := Module[
  {m = Join[mat, IdentityMatrix@Length@mat, 2], l, a},
  l = {augmentedMatrixForm[m]};
  Do[a = m[[i, i]];
   {AppendTo[l, makeDivTag[i, a]]; m = divMat[m, i, a];
    AppendTo[l, augmentedMatrixForm[m]],
    AppendTo[l, makeRedTag[m, i]]; m = redMat[m, i];
    AppendTo[l, augmentedMatrixForm[m]]},
   {i, Length[m]}]; 
  Partition[Drop[l, -2], 2] // Grid // TraditionalForm // Print;
  augmentedMatrixForm[m]
  ]

rowReduce[testMat]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Table` and `MapAt` with `Span` can reduce the code to almost two lines:

```
n = 3;
A = RandomInteger[10, {n, n}];
MatrixForm[A]
```

[image]

```
LU = Join[A, IdentityMatrix[n], 2];
res = Table[{LU = MapAt[#/LU[[k, k]] &, LU, k], 
    LU = MapAt[# - #[[k]] LU[[k]] &, LU, k + 1 ;;]}, {k, n}];
Map[augmentedMatrixForm, res, {2}] // Grid
```

[image]

With "tags" it is a bit longer

```
LU = Join[A, IdentityMatrix[n], 2];
res = Join @@ Table[{If[k > 1, {(Subscript[r, #] -> Subscript[r, #] - 
   Subscript[r, k - 1] LU[[#, k - 1]]) & /@ Range[k, n], 
       LU = MapAt[# - #[[k - 1]] LU[[k - 1]] &, LU, k ;;]}, {"", LU}], 
   {Subscript[r, k] -> Subscript[r, k]/LU[[k, k]], 
      LU = MapAt[#/LU[[k, k]] &, LU, k]}}, {k, n}];
MapAt[TableForm, MapAt[augmentedMatrixForm, res, {All, 2}], {All, 1}] // Grid
```

[image]

P.S. I didn't check the degeneracy of the matrix.

Comment: @Tangshutao Which version do you use? This syntax was added in recent versions of Mathematica. You can use `Range[k+1,n]` instead of `k+1;;`.